# Python problem in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to use climate data provided by "WordClim" for specific points in a shapefile. However, this error appears after the data has been run through the "Point Sampling Tool" in QGIS. How can I fix this?

The error:

> ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point. 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/Gerson Rodrigues/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\pointsamplingtool\doPointSamplingTool.py", line 317, in accept
> if not self.sampling(outPath, tableName):
> File "C:\Users/Gerson Rodrigues/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\pointsamplingtool\doPointSamplingTool.py", line 382, in sampling
> pointPoint = pointGeom.asPoint()
> ValueError: Null geometry cannot be converted to a point.

Versão do Python: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
Versão do QGIS: 3.28.14-Firenze Firenze, b09131c512
[image]

Comment: The error message appears to indicate the dataset has a NULL for at least one geometry record, so I would start by running some checks on the input dataset to make sure:  1) every record has a geometry, 2) every geometry is valid.

Comment: You can also try field calculator with the expression `raster_value( layer:='dem', band:=1, point:=$geometry)`. Replace `dem` with the name of your raster layer. It will calculate a new column with the raster value at each point

Comment: The solutions worked. Thank you guys.